# SyncSort JOINKEYS - Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, jcl, reformat

Can Syncsort produce an array when performing the JOINKEYS with the REFORMAT functions?  My Data example looks like this:

**File #1**

```
Kevin    Florida
Darren   Georgia
Travis   Colorado
Todd     Louisiana
```

**File #2**

```
Kevin   Purple
Kevin   Gold
Darren  Red
Darren  White
Travis  Black
Travis  Gold
Todd    Blue
Todd    White
```

**Output File**

```
Kevin   Florida    Purple   Gold
Darren  Georgia    Red      White
Travis  Colorado   Black    Gold
Todd    Louisiana  Blue     White
```

I can successfully perform the JOINKEY and REFORMAT when there is basically a 1:1 within the file.  However, I was not sure if I could create a 1:M output file in a single record without overlaying data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I my 'SORT FIELDS' card was set up to sort the key from file one in ascending order.  So, I presorted the files in a previous step then performed the JOINKEYS in the following step.  This time my sort card was:

```
'SORT FIELDS=COPY'.
```

This did the trick.